# How to use Change Data Capture with Entity Faramework CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, code-first, change-data-capture

I want create report from Change Data Capture on some web app builded on ASP.NET MVC and EF. EF using Code First and the database is created in dbo schem. CDC generate tables under cdc scheme in system tables of database that using EF. 
Maybe anybody have expiriense in this issue? How create EF context for CDC tables?
I'm trying to find information about this issue but did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could look to enable CDC on the DB side, and then create views to access the data. In our organization we use a separate DB do hive the CDC data into a persisted state, and that allows for referencing from the app.